# PySpark - using concat function raises exception even with simple string constants

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and trying to concatenate string to build xpath expression. I have already narrowed down possibilities to this particular line (no exception if it is commented out).

```py
xpath_text = concat('test', 'test')
```

Earlier I had variables in `concat` function, but first I need to sort above. I know Python offers plenty of possibilities to operate on data frames, but how you do this on variables?

raises exception:

> INC_03070101: Transformation error [Error An error occurred while
> calling o77.**getnewargs**. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method
> **getnewargs**([]) does not exist ('Py4JError', ':', Py4JError(u'An error occurred while calling o77.**getnewargs**.
> Trace:\npy4j.Py4JException: Method **getnewargs**([]) does not
> exist\n\tat
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)\n\tat
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)\n\tat
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)\n\tat
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat
> py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n\n',))

Comment: `text1 = 'test'
text2 = 'test'
xpath_text = text1 + text2`

Answer (score 0):

I answered it myself after browsing through more pages in google search. Simple + operator was the answer. Not sure why google was presenting result related to data frames persistently.